# Execute selective actions on controllers on https in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My requirement to run selective action methods on https and rest should be execute on https.

To achieve this I created custom attribute and set on actions.

```
public class RequiresSSL : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpResponseBase res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        //Check if we're secure or not and if we're on the local box
        if (!req.IsSecureConnection && !req.IsLocal) 
        {
            var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url)
            {
                Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
                Port = 443
            };
            res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**Setting up on Actions**

```
    [RequireHttps]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      ..
    }
```

Actions are executing in https which are having attribute as "RequireHttps" but I got problem that actions which are not having attribute are still executing on https which is not required.

Can you point that what am I doing wrong here? or suggest me good solution to execute actions on https or http as per requirement.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. links will be rendered using your current protocal. The redirect changes it to https. You'll have to detect this with a seperate attribute and redirect back to http. I suggest doing nothing and allowing it to run in https.

Comment: If I will have to create separate attribute then I would need to put attribute on many actions methodx, which is I think not good solution. I cannot allow to run in https because it might slow down some of pages and page designs also corrupted in some areas.

Comment: Honestly why not run 100% ssl and focus on those problems instead of trying this weird mixed action setup?

Comment: When you hit a brick wall, the correct response is to evaluate what you're doing, not bash your head until the wall comes down or your brains fall out, whichever occurs first. There's simply no reason to ever redirect a user *from* HTTPS *to* HTTP, hence why there's no built-in way to do it. That should be your indication that perhaps what you're trying to do is misguided.